# Составить команду при помощи dos2unix

Tags: linux, bash

У меня в системе какое-то приложение напакостило и некоторые файлы превратила из LF в CR LF. И при этом она сделала это рандомно, т.е. нужно написать команду, которая нашла бы "испорченные" файлы и при помощи команды dos2unix.

Comment: Бинарные файлы испортишь...

Comment: Используй *find ... -mtime ...*.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну не преустанавливать же? я помню, что как то они отличаются.

Comment: `file` показывает тип файла. Для текстовых - ещё и байты переноса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На скорую руку на ум пришёл в голову (я употребил 2,5 фразеологизма подряд, а вам слабо?) такой однострок:

```
find -type f \
    -exec sh -c 'file -b --mime-type "$0" |grep text >/dev/null' '{}' \; \
    -exec sh -c 'grep "$0" "$1" >/dev/null' "$(echo -ne '\r')"   '{}' \;  \
    -print
```

Первый `-exec` с помощью `file` определяет, что файл текстовый, а второй, что он содержит `\r`, но напрямую я бы это скармливать `dos2unix`'у не стал, а хотя бы пробежался бы глазами.

И ещё некоторые файлы могут быть с концом строки Win изначально, например, какие-то файлы mono.

ЗЫ: для верности я бы всё же сделал потом переустановку всех пакетов.